How to handle unsigned long integers when returning values from C?
This is my function in C:
uint64_t f(){
    return 2147483648;
}

This is my function template specification:
:Begin:
:Function:       f
:Pattern:        f[]
:Arguments:      {}
:ArgumentTypes:  {}
:ReturnType:     Integer
:End:

When I install the executable and run it in Mathematica, it returns the number with a negative sign, probably because the sign bit is set. How do I deal with this correctly?
In[2]:= link = Install["integer"]

Out[2]= LinkObject["'/Users/sau/Desktop/wstp/integer'", 232, 14]

In[3]:= f[]

Out[3]= -2147483648

